# How to strip out final hyphen character

Tags: regex

I'm using Regex (in ColdFusion) to replace non-alphanumeric characters with hyphens e.g.

```
#REReplace("MyString (NewString)", "[^a-z0-9]", "-")#
```

Because the closing bracket in a string `)` is also converted to a hyphen `-`, I am getting a trailing hyphen which I want to remove. Instead of this `MyString-NewString-` I want `MyString-NewString`.

What is the regex pattern to match for a trailing hyphen? I thought it was `(.*)-?` but it doesn't work for me. Obviously I am nesting several REReplace functions to get the result I want but can't get the regex pattern correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern to match a trailing hyphen would be

```
-$
```

`$` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matching the end of the string.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to match. I get this error: `Malformed regular expression "[^(.*)-$]"`

Comment: I put the complete regex you need in my answer. Why are you putting brackets and other stuff around it?

Comment: `[^(.*)-$]` is a negated character class, that matches anything but "(", ".", "*", and a range from ")" to "$". The range is probably illegal, therefor the error

Comment: Okay I have changed it to [-$] and its still not working? The trailing hyphen still exists.

Comment: Just use `-$`  !!! and not `[^-$]` **the square brackets create a character class**

Comment: oh right! yes it works now! voted as answer, thank you my friend!

Comment: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) is a good place to learn regex.

Answer (score 1):

1. First remove all the trailing special characters with an empty string. And store the final result to a string variable.

   Regex: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]$` Replacement string =`""`
2. Now replace one or more special characters with `-`

   Regex: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` Replacement string = `"-"`

Comment: But the final closing bracket ) should not be a '-'

Comment: yes. remove all the trailing special characters. so the final `)` would be gone.

Comment: Thanks for this Avinash but it wasn't quite what I needed. I am doing other replacements to replace spaces with hyphens as well. It was just the final hyphen I wanted to remove. Gave an up vote for your effort.